# Websocket Rails Standalone сервер после ~200~300 запросов отключается. SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

Ruby on rails 4.2.0. Gem Websocket-rails 0.7.0. На клиенте Angular, посылает запросы асинхронно.

Инициализирую соединение в ангуляре (coffeescript):

```
dispatcher = new WebSocketRails('ws://192.168.1.101:3001/websocket')
```

Посылаю запросы (coffeescript):

```
dispatcher.trigger('contacts.filtered', {filtered:filtered}, filter_contacts_success, filter_contacts_failure)
```

В файле events.rb, прописано в какой контроллер идти и какой метод:

```
namespace :contacts do
  subscribe :filtered, to: UserWebsocketController, with_method: :filter_contacts
end
```

Сам метод упростил, проще некуда:

```
def filter_contacts
  puts "message:#{message}"

  @response[:filtered_contacts] = []
  @response[:success] = true
  trigger_success @response
end
```

Работает, но бывает сервер отваливается и в логи пишет:

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

После того как я упросил метод, в логи web-socket'a ошибок не выводит, просто говорит, что сервер выключен:

```
Server Removed: C2IHQCt_Wd6RyAEo1s0AkQ
```

А в логи web-socket сервера, говорит:

```
/home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:159:in `dup': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
  from /home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:159:in `block in as_json'
  from /home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:159:in `each'
  from /home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:159:in `map'
  from /home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:159:in `as_json'
  from /home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:159:in `block in as_json'
  from /home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:159:in `each'
  from /home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:159:in `map'
  from /home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:159:in `as_json'
  ... 493 levels...
  from /home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/websocket-rails-0.7.0/lib/websocket_rails/dispatcher.rb:65:in `block (3 levels) in route'
  from /home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/websocket-rails-0.7.0/lib/websocket_rails/logging.rb:66:in `call'
  from /home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/websocket-rails-0.7.0/lib/websocket_rails/logging.rb:66:in `log_event'
  from /home/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/websocket-rails-0.7.0/lib/websocket_rails/dispatcher.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in route'
```

и соответственно на клиенте в консоль выдает:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.101:3001/websocket' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Потому что сервер отключился.

Но что за ошибка в ActiveSupport'овском модуле object/json.rb в блоке as_json.

```
stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Вот этот блок as_json:

```
class Hash
  def as_json(options = nil) #:nodoc:
    # create a subset of the hash by applying :only or :except
    subset = if options
      if attrs = options[:only]
        slice(*Array(attrs))
      elsif attrs = options[:except]
        except(*Array(attrs))
      else
        self
      end
    else
      self
    end

    Hash[subset.map { |k, v| [k.to_s, options ? v.as_json(options.dup) : v.as_json] }]
  end
end
```

А именно строчка 159:

```
Hash[subset.map { |k, v| [k.to_s, options ? v.as_json(options.dup) : v.as_json] }]
```

Дальше не копал. Думаю в геме ошибки не должно быть. 
Интересует почему же 100-200 запросов проходят удачно, а потом, после очередного запроса, сервер падает.

Подскажите в какую сторону копать? 
Или может как продебажить websocket контроллер? Обычный дебаг в Rubymine 7, когда ставлю breackpoint не заходит в контроллер наследуемый от WebsocketRails::BaseController (а в обычные контроллеры заходит).

Comment: А какой сервер приложений используется для standalone websocket-сервера?

Comment: @MAXOPKA, Используется обычный рельсовый Thin, приложение на 3000 порту, websocket-сервер на 3001. Запускаю его:  `rake websocket_rails:start_server RAILS_ENV=production`. Насколько я понял вопрос.

Comment: @MAXOPKA, а на другом сервере nginx с passenger'ом, но вебсокет там также отключается.